# Soap wsa:To specification at curl command line

Tags: bash, wcf, curl, soap

How can I compose a `curl` command line that contains a `wsa:To` Soap specification for example `http://myserver.services.com/Services/ServiceUsers.svc?wsdl`?

Comment: I think this may require the use of Custom Message Encoder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder

Comment: @DingPeng, the problem is that I need it is to run a command line directly on a Linux server

Comment: That may not be supported, WCF relies on the .net framework, and the .net framework is not cross-platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end this is not what I wanted but I managed to achieve my goal. The solution was to use the `--data` argument followed by the `xml request` corresponding to the request and in it put the `wsa:To` header. By example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://myserver.services.com/Services/ServiceUsers.svc' --header 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8' --data '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://tempuri.org/IServiceUsers/UsersList</wsa:Action><wsa:To>http://myserver.services.com/Services/ServiceUsers.svc</wsa:To></soap:Header><soap:Body><tem:UsersList/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'
```

Thanks to @DingPeng for his help, you may be right about the availability of the .Net framework