# WCF Test Client - how to give xml file as input

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, wcftestclient

We have a WCF application and we would like to test one of the end points which takes a class object as input(which is generated by XML to class conversion). I am trying to test this using WCF Test Client.

I have the incoming XML data which has too many nodes. In WCF Test Client, it is asking me to enter each and every element separately. Is there any other way where I can input XML file/data and it generates the data to WCF Test Client? or is there any better way to test the WCF service locally?

Comment: Just build a test console app to implement the client you need for your WCF service. Alternatively use SOAPUI, Postman or even simple CURL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67220270/soap-wsato-specification-at-curl-command-line

Comment: You can use the ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool to generate a client for testing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe

Comment: You must be using the XSD.exe to generate the c# classes from the XML schema.  So using Xml Deserialization will fill the classes with data.  Data can then come from either a stream or from a string.  The WCF then would need access to the instance of root class that is generated by the xml deserialization.